How to record screen on ubuntu?
I have questions to ask. I use ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS when I press "PrtSc Button" It will appear screenshot and screen recording button but now I install MacOS theme on Ubuntu, So recording button was missing. How to solve this problem or Do you have any app to advcie?
Thank you for all answers.
Sorry for bad English grammar

Edit your question and add how you installed MacOS theme?

press on keyboard Shift+Ctrl+Alt+R .The video will be in $HOME/Videos/.

@petep Thank you. It work!

@user68186 I watch tutorial on youtube.

Check this out https://itsfoss.com/kooha-screen-recorder/

Maybe someone post those comments (& contents of the link) as an answer?
